# bxSlider not working automatically

Tags: javascript, slideshow, bxslider

I want the bxSlider to automatically start the slideshow without the user clicking on it. This is my code (which isn't working):

```
slider = $('.slider1').bxSlider({
    slideWidth: 1012,
    slideHeight:200,
    minSlides: 1,
    slideMargin: 0,
    controls: false,
    auto: true,
    autoStart: true
});
slider.startAuto();
```

What's wrong with this? What happens is that images do load, but it never autoscrolls, the user always have to choose one of the pager dots to manually scroll through. What's wrong with my code?

Comment: you already have `autoStart:true` and `auto: true`.?? so why you add `slider.startAuto();`..? see **[Link here](http://bxslider.com/examples/auto-show-start-stop-controls)**

Comment: in desperation, hoping that one of them will work. But even without it, it wasn't working, that's why I added it.

Comment: See **[Link here](http://bxslider.com/examples/auto-show-start-stop-controls)**

Comment: I've seen that link but that's not completely automatic, the user still has to click on the "start" button. I want it to get rolling as soon as it loads, without any user interaction.

Answer (score 4):

You should use

```
 $(document).ready(function(e) {    });
```

or

```
 $(window).ready(function(e) {    });
```

in between the code.

so the correct one should be,

```
 $(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('.slider1').bxSlider({
        slideWidth: 1012,
        slideHeight:200,
        minSlides: 1,
        slideMargin: 0,
        controls: false,
        auto: true,

    });
    });
```

hope this will help you...!

Comment: auto: true, <-worked for me instead of autoStart:true

Answer (score 2):

This Code worked for me!

```
var slider = $('#slider').bxSlider();

$('.bx-next, .bx-prev, .bx-pager a').click(function(){
    // time to wait (in ms)
    var wait = 1000;
    setTimeout(function(){
        slider.startAuto();
    }, wait);
});
```

You can set wait on 0 if you don't want a delay. And because I used: pagerCustom: '#pager', I changed '.bx-pager' a into '#pager a'.

Answer (score 2):

This was all , what was missing and i got it from `bxslider official` page

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
  mode: 'fade',
  auto: true,
  autoControls: true,
  pause: 2000
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try  setting `autoControls: true` (from http://bxslider.com/examples/auto-show-start-stop-controls)

Comment: I did, but the user still has to click on the "start" button. I want it to get rolling as soon as it loads, without any user interaction. (Also, I don't want to show the controls.)

Comment: Well, you could use `display:none` to hide the controls via CSS, though this obviously isn't optimal. 

Which version of the slider are you using? Looking at the API (http://v3.bxslider.com/options), you could try setting 'autoDelay: 0'.

Comment: I tried autoDelay:0, it didn't make a difference :( I'm using the latest version? I just downloaded it today, it's version 4.1

Answer (score 1):

Okay! I got the same problem! And none of the solution worked above. But I found what was wrong!

1 - First Check and make sure you have `auto:true` in jQuery script like below:

```
$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
          auto: true,
          pause: 3000,
          pager: true
 });
```

2 - The main jQuery file that you are using, kindly update that jQuery file, you might be using old jQuery file! (#2 was the issue in case of mine)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This code is also working perfectly

```
jQuery(function(e){
jQuery('.bxslider').bxSlider({
    mode: 'fade',
    captions: true,
    autoplay:true,
    autoControls: true,
    auto: true,
    autoplaySpeed:1000
  });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I suggest the following remedy. `onSlideAfter` is executed after each slide transition. Then this code will cause `slider.startAuto()` to be executed each time this happens, starting auto show.

```
var slider = $(".sliderBx ul").bxSlider({
     auto: true,
     pager: true,
     controls: true,
     onSlideAfter: function () {
      slider.startAuto();
    }
});
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Please include an explanation.